# keeping order after breakpoint in react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, responsive, react-grid-layout

I'm using [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues)  with responsive design.
In my configuration I have two cards (for example)-

```
Large screen- A (left, 6 columns), B(on A's right- 6 columns)
Medium screen-A (left, 4 columns), B(on A's right- 4 columns)
```

When a user is in Large screen- he reorders the cards so that

```
B- on the left; A- on the right
```

Then he shrinks the screen

```
**Expected:** the order will stay B on left, A on the right, but both 4 columns width.
**Actual:** exactly as configured.
```

When the user goes back to Large- the order is as expected.

Any thoughts on how to implement our expected behavior?